# DataTable Filter From Code Side C#

Tags: c#, .net, filter, datatable

I have a DataTable which I get by an upload of CSV document from the user and has columns, rows like that:

```
Email      Age      Team
x@x.com    25       BarcelonaFC
y@y.com    32       BesiktasJK
z@z.com    18       Napoli
y@y.com    19       Boca Juniors
x@x.com    36       Internazionale
```

I need to filter that datatable before I insert it into the database. Email column should be unique. So I need to filter that datatable so that I get as a result eliminating 2 rows. I do not want to use LINQ, but if it is only solution, its ok.

```
Email      Age      Team
x@x.com    25       BarcelonaFC
y@y.com    32       BesiktasJK
z@z.com    18       Napoli
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use LINQ?

Comment: Project Manager does not want me to use it :)

Comment: My code is so simple, I get csv document and load it to datatable as columns are decided with comma seperated values. 

DataTable DtSubscribers = LoadUploadedCsvDocument(ViewState["UploadedCSVFilePath"].ToString());

Comment: So, what constitutes the correct value... First one in for a given email??? and disregard anything AFTER that?

Comment: yes like that, i have to lose data. those will be AFTER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `HashSet<string>` holding email addresses, then loop backwards through the table, add the email address for each row to the hashset, and, if it's already there (if `Add` returns false), remove the row.

Comment: Thanks alot, I will try, can you give an alternative solution with LINQ please.

Comment: LINQ wouldn't do much good here; it's meant for queries, not modifications.  You can get unique emails by writing `table.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<String>("Email")).Distinct()`

Comment: @Kelly: Otherwise, you'll skip indices as you remove items.

Comment: @Yagiz: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: That Actually worked out great @SLaks. I did the same thing with HashTable for 1.000.000 rows, it resulted in 21 seconds. HashSet resulted in ~2 seconds. Great Collection for duplicate logic. But why backwards, can you clear that out pls? Thanks again

Comment: @Yagiz: Otherwise, you'll skip indices as you remove items.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this....

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt = yourCurrentDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Email", "Age", "Team");
```

Comment: I already did that, that does not clear duplicate rows. You cannot give true parameter which is for distinct to sprecified column(email).

Comment: Exactly where I was going... create a new table of "Distinct" values on the given columns...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary for it:

First of all, you can create simple class:

```
class Data
{
  public int Age;
  public string Team;
}
```

After that you can insert your data to dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, MyData> dic = new Dictionary<string, MyData>();
foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable)
{
  if(!dic.ContainsKey(row[.. email ..])) 
  {
    dic.Add(..., ...);
  }
}
```

Now your dictionary ready to go...